# How do I import the updated oracle table partition into the hive table later?

Tags: oracle, hive, bigdata

I have an Oracle table called ABC where daily ETL. Likewise, I have a HIVE table named ABC.

I ingest partitions from ORACLE table to HIVE table daily. However, the new data in the Oracle table may contain old records and is inserted into the old partition.

I am missing the data in the updated old partitions in the oracle table where I ingest the new partitions in the oracle table into the hive table.

So, when I import new partitions like in the Oracle table, I want to update the data added to the old partitions in the Hive table when the old partitions are updated.

How can I set up a structure to avoid this problem?

P.S : Partitions contain ~250 millions of records.